# What is the way to clear the tlog without taking the log backup?

Tags: sql-server

I have a db in full recovery model.

The tlog keeps growing due to the recovery model, and taking a log backup truncates the log.

Is there any alternate way to do the same, but without doing a backup? My goal is that I need to truncate the log and I don't want to have a backup file.

Comment: Backup to `NUL`

Comment: if you dont want the log to grow and dont want to backup, why not change to simple recovery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentionned by Bob Klimes, if you are not keeping the transaction log, it does not make that much sense to have the database set to full recovery model.

I'm thinking maybe you do it because you are using a feature that requires it, like Availability Groups. But if you do, then I'm also thinking that the data in this DB is probably important (otherwise, why would you implement HA).

If this data is important, then you should take those log backup and keep them as safe as your full/diff backups (Please don't tell me you do not take full/diff backups).
Replication doesn't protect the data from everything so having complete backups (including logs) could be a life saver.

Comment: Does simple model have any less features compared to full model (besides the fact that you cannot take tlog backup)?

Comment: Hi Aaron. My question is that- being in full recovery model, whether there is any alternative to log backups to clear the tlog as I don't want to have backup files. I know that changing to simple model is one solution, but as mentioned in my question I want to remain in full recovery model. I'm just trying to see the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. Agree with your point. That doc helped. Can't delete this question. Tried.